# Defining function with an argument, employs while loop and returns largest power of 2 that is less than or equal to number

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Write a program in Python that defines a function that takes a single argument, a positive integer. The function should employ a while loop, and return the largest power of two that is less than or equal to the number. So, for example, if the function was called with the value 133, it would return 128, and if it was called with 19, it would return 16. 
Please include a number of function calls in your code to test your function beneath its definition.

The answer in simplest python code would be best thanks.

P.S. Im no expert with python so details would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're not a code-writing service. Please make an attempt to solve this on your own. If you run into trouble with a *specific* piece, come back and ask about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple while loop works, just make sure you divide the number by 2, otherwise you'll get the NEXT power of 2.

```
def function(number):
    x = 1
    while x <= number:
        x *= 2
    return x / 2
```